# creating new column values according to filters

Tags: python, pandas

I applied these conditions to my dataframe. If all these conditions are TRUE, I want to create an integer column with the value 1, but I don't know how to create this final step.

my final goal is having something in the style of case when in SQL

```
df.loc[df['AREA'].isin([8,22,19,27,22]) | (df['AREA']==4) & (~df['REGION'].isin([53,65,86])) | (df['AREA']==1) & (df['company']==1)]
```

Comment: And what confuses you specifically?

Comment: my doubt was how to create this final target variable if these conditions are verified, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest create each masks separately and pass to [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
m1 = df['AREA'].isin([8,22,19,27,22])
m2 = (df['AREA']==4) & (~df['REGION'].isin([53,65,86])) 
m3 = (df['AREA']==1) & (df['company']==1)

df['new'] = np.select([m1, m2, m3], [1,2,3], default=0)
```

Comment: thanks but in real life I have something in the style of case when in SQl, so I have several combinations and my target value will have several different values. do you still suggest masks? thanks

Comment: @progster So you want `df['new'] = df['AREA'].isin([8,22,19,27,22]) | (df['AREA']==4) & (~df['REGION'].isin([53,65,86])) | (df['AREA']==1) & (df['company']==1)` ?

Comment: yes I want to create a df['new'] column, if these conditions are true the value will be 1. Then I have other condintions and the value will be 2, etc, in the style of case when in SQL

Comment: @progster - Answer was edited. Created 3 separate masks like for sample data.